# Infeasible solution to scheduling problem using ortools

Tags: python, optimization, scheduling, or-tools, cp-sat

I'm trying to create a scheduler which assigns a set of shifts to a set of drivers for each day of the week, enforcing a minimum of 1 Day off per week. For the following input data, I'm getting an infeasible solution. Any help?

Input data:

```
        dow  driver   hub
0      Sunday  1       S
1      Sunday  2       S
2      Sunday  3       S
3      Monday  1       S
4      Monday  2       S
5      Monday  3       S
6     Tuesday  2       S
7     Tuesday  3       S
8   Wednesday  1       S
9   Wednesday  3       S
10   Thursday  1       S
11   Thursday  2       S
12   Thursday  3       S
13     Friday  1       S
14     Friday  2       S
15   Saturday  1       S
16   Saturday  2       S
17   Saturday  3       S
```

Code

```
from ortools.sat.python import cp_model
import pandas as pd


def create_shift_schedule(drivers,
                          shifts,
                          week_days,
                          hubs,
                          min_shift_drivers,
                          max_shift_drivers,
                          driver_hubs_relationships):
    model = cp_model.CpModel()

    # Create shift variables
    schedule = {}
    for e in drivers:
        for d in week_days:
            for s in shifts:
                for r in hubs:
                    schedule[(e, d, s, r)] = model.NewBoolVar(f'schedule_{e}_{d}_{s}_{r}')

    # Each driver works exactly one shift per day (including "Off" shift) at a specific hub
    for e in drivers:
        for d in week_days:
            model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for s in shifts for r in hubs) == 1)

    # Respect the minimum and maximum number of drivers per shift per hub per day
    for d in week_days:
        for s in shifts:
            for r in hubs:
                min_drivers = min_shift_drivers.get((d, s, r), 0)
                max_drivers = max_shift_drivers.get((d, s, r), len(drivers))
                model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for e in drivers) >= min_drivers)
                model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for e in drivers) <= max_drivers)

    # Ensure each driver has at least one "Off" shift per week and max 3 "off" shifts per week
    for e in drivers:
        model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, "Off", r)] for d in week_days for r in hubs) >= 1)
    for e in drivers:
        model.Add(sum(schedule[(e, d, "Off", r)] for d in week_days for r in hubs) <= 3)

    # Assign each driver to their specific hub
    for e in drivers:
        for r in hubs:
            if r not in driver_hubs_relationships[e]:
                for d in week_days:
                    for s in shifts:
                        model.Add(schedule[(e, d, s, r)] == 0)

    # Minimize the total number of working shifts assigned to drivers (excluding "Off" shift)
    # model.Minimize(sum(
    #         schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for e in drivers for d in week_days for s in shifts if
    #         s != "Off" for r in hubs))

    # Create auxiliary variables
    same_shift_aux = {}
    for e1 in drivers:
        for e2 in drivers:
            if e1 != e2:
                for d in week_days:
                    for s in shifts:
                        if s != "Off":
                            for r in hubs:
                                same_shift_aux[(e1, e2, d, s, r)] = model.NewBoolVar(
                                    f'same_shift_aux_{e1}_{e2}_{d}_{s}_{r}')

    # Add constraints to link auxiliary variables with schedule variables
    for e1 in drivers:
        for e2 in drivers:
            if e1 != e2:
                for d in week_days:
                    for s in shifts:
                        if s != "Off":
                            for r in hubs:
                                model.AddImplication(schedule[(e1, d, s, r)],
                                                     same_shift_aux[(e1, e2, d, s, r)])
                                model.AddImplication(schedule[(e2, d, s, r)],
                                                     same_shift_aux[(e1, e2, d, s, r)])

    # Modify the objective function
    penalty_for_same_shift = 1  # Adjust this value to control the penalty for assigning the same
    # shift to multiple drivers
    model.Minimize(
            sum(schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for e in drivers for d in week_days for s in shifts if
                s != "Off" for r in hubs)
            + penalty_for_same_shift * sum(
                    same_shift_aux[(e1, e2, d, s, r)] for e1 in drivers for e2 in drivers if
                    e1 != e2 for d in week_days for s in shifts if s != "Off" for r in hubs))

    # Solve the scheduling problem
    solver = cp_model.CpSolver()
    solver.parameters.max_time_in_seconds = 300.0
    solver.parameters.log_search_progress = True
    status = solver.Solve(model)
    print(f"status code {status}")
    if status == cp_model.OPTIMAL:
        solution = {}
        for e in drivers:
            solution[e] = {}
            for d in week_days:
                for s in shifts:
                    for r in hubs:
                        if solver.Value(schedule[(e, d, s, r)]) == 1:
                            solution[e][d] = (s, r)
        return solution
    else:
        return None


file = pd.Dataframe(input_data) # i'm loading them from a file

file['driver'] = file['driver'].apply(lambda x: str(x))

drivers = file['driver'].unique().tolist()
num_shifts = 2  # Including "Off" shift
# Create shift assignment variables
shifts = ["Off"] + [f"Shift_{d}" for d in range(1, num_shifts)]
week_days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday']
hubs = file['hub'].unique().tolist()

# how many drivers are needed per dow and per hub
hub_counts = \
    pd.DataFrame(file.groupby(['dow', 'hub'],
                              as_index=False)['driver'].count())

fixed_shift_drivers_per_day_hub = {
    day: {
        hub: driver_count
        for hub, driver_count in zip(hub_counts[hub_counts['dow'] == day]['hub'],
                                     hub_counts[hub_counts['dow'] == day]['driver'])
    }
    for day in week_days
}
min_shift_drivers = {
    (day, shift, hub): 1
    for day in week_days
    for shift in shifts
    for hub in hubs
}

max_shift_drivers = {
    (day, shift, hub): fixed_shift_drivers_per_day_hub[day][hub] if shift != "Off" else 0
    for day in week_days
    for shift in shifts
    for hub in hubs
}

driver_hubs_relationships = \
    pd.DataFrame(file.groupby('driver')['hub'].apply(list)).reset_index()
driver_hubs_relationships = \
    {key: value for key, value in zip(driver_hubs_relationships['driver'],
                                      driver_hubs_relationships['hub'])}


solution = create_shift_schedule(drivers, shifts, week_days, hubs, min_shift_drivers,
                                 max_shift_drivers, driver_hubs_relationships)

if solution:
    for e in drivers:
        print(f"{e}:")
        for d in week_days:
            print(f"  {d}: {solution[e][d]}")
else:
    print("No solution found.")
```

Comment: If it's feasible, attach enforcement literal (using OnlyEnforceIf) to each of the constraints and maximize the sum to identity the infeasible constraints.

Comment: Could it be possible to showcase the changes and formally reply to accept the answer? I've tried what you've said but perhaps I'm still missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This constraint seems to be causing the issue. `min_drivers` can't be more than `max_drivers`.

```
# Respect the minimum and maximum number of drivers per shift per hub per day
    for d in week_days:
        for s in shifts:
            for r in hubs:
                min_drivers = min_shift_drivers.get((d, s, r), 0)
                max_drivers = max_shift_drivers.get((d, s, r), len(drivers))
                if min_drivers > max_drivers:  # Added this check.
                    continue
                expr = sum(schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for e in drivers)
                model.AddLinearConstraint(expr, min_drivers, max_drivers) # L Perron's suggestion.
```

Comment: `model.AddLinearConstraint(sum(...), min_drivers, max_drivers)` is a bit easier on the presolve.

Comment: @LaurentPeron I'm trying also to understand what is the practical different of just minimising this:     

model.Minimize(sum(
            schedule[(e, d, s, r)] for e in drivers for d in week_days for s in shifts if
            s != "Off" for r in hubs))

Comment: without the creation of the auxiliary vars